# How to know whom has started/completed a milestone in cases?

Tags: case, servicecloud, entitlements, casemilestone

In our case solution a case can vary on terms of ownership and then comes our need to get the name of the agent that achieved/violated each milestone within the case.

We expected to get this information dynamically (reports/dashboards), which is not possible since we can´t edit the `Cases with Milestones` report type, nor even create a new report...

Querying the object `CaseMilestone` we have the field called `CreatedById`, each we expect to be the doer of a specific milestone. Even it's not the best scenario (manually do it) we can retrieve this field. Then I tried to get the `CreatedBy.Name` relationship query, but dataloader doesn't support it. So I will need to perform extractions over extractions then cross references with an external tool, like Excel.

Do you have any idea or insight on how could we improve this activity?

Answer (score 0):

We have ideas for the same requirements:

Idea Link: Show Completed by on Case Milestone Page and in reports

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdbCPUAZ/show-completed-by-on-case-milestone-page-and-in-reports